# How to launch a 2D character toward the mouse position?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, physics, movement

I want to launch a 2D character using the mouse, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the character to move left or right during the launch. Its as if the code is ignoring the X axis almost entirely; it will kinda "teleport" if i set the launch force to be super high but not by as much as the vertical movement.

```
private void airdash()
{
    mouseposition = playcam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector2 aimdirection = mouseposition - playerbody.position;
           
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        aimdirection = aimdirection.normalized;
        playerbody.velocity = (new Vector2(aimdirection.x * airdashforce, aimdirection.y * airdashforce));
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your playerbody controlled by physics?  If the vertical is working, perhaps the horizontal velocity is being quickly reduced due to friction on the physics object it's touching?

Comment: it is controlled by physics but it acts the same even mid air

Comment: Is there no other code that is affecting the velocity of the player?

Comment: What's your camera setup like? Are you using a perspective camera or applying any rotation to it?

Comment: only the movement script should be affecting velocity right now, and that should be overwritten by the air dash script, and im using the camera to get the mouse position to then get the angle between the mouse and the player.

Comment: never mind im kinda dumb, the move script was messing with it. new problem though now i need to fix my move script and make the dash work far better